# How can I make the width of a list item larger than the width of its list?

Tags: css, html-lists

I have a list whose width is set in pixels. It has two list items: One whose content is shorter than the list, and one whose content extends past the width.

How can I make it so that the list items each have a width equal to the larger of the list width and the list item content width (so that the second item in this example contains its content)?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  width: 400px;

  overflow-x: scroll;
  outline: 1px dashed red;
}

li {
  max-width: none;
  min-width: 100%;

  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;

  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: skyblue;
  outline: 1px dashed blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: inline-block` instead of `display: block` so the width of the list is wrap to the content

Sample below:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  width: 400px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  outline: 1px dashed red;
}

li {
  /* Inline block's default width is wrap to the content, but there's also other differences between inline-block and block */
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: skyblue;
  outline: 1px dashed blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test</li>
</ul>
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: Thanks! That got me to my desired effect. If you care to edit, I needed to keep the fixed width on the `ul` and to put the `inline-block` on the `li`. This allows for longer items to flow past the container list.

Comment: Hi @Corey, does that means what you are trying to achieve is `ul` is fixed width (eg. 400px) but `li` can be any width but can go past `400px`? Thanks

Comment: Yes, almost. `li` is at least the container width (400px) and at most its content width. Your solution got me there with the two changes I mentioned (`ul { width: 400px; }` and `li { display: inline-block; }`).

Comment: Hi @Corey, modified the solution! Btw `max-width` is not required in that case :)

Answer (score -1):

make the container `display: grid` and both items will extend to the largest one

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  width: 400px;
  display: grid;

  overflow-x: scroll;
  outline: 1px dashed red;
}

li {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;

  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: skyblue;
  outline: 1px dashed blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test</li>
</ul>
```